# How to reverse iterate a nested multimap

Tags: java, iterator, guava, multimap

I have a nested mulimap and need to iterate the outer level in **reverse order**.

```
private Multimap<Integer, Multimap<String, String>> stockMatrix 
    = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

forward iteration is fine

```
for (Multimap<String, String> oneRow : stockMatrix.values()) {
..........
}
```

I looked at using a for loop from stockMatrix.size() but that gives me the count of all inner MultiMap pairs instead of just the number in the outer level.

Comment: Since you use Guava, why don't you use a `Table` instead?

Comment: [`Collections.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) ?

Comment: @fge Because `Table<R,C,V>` is roughly equal to `Map<R,Map<C,V>>` not `Multimap<R,Multimap<C,V>>`. Nevertheless, OP's use of these collections seems like code smell to me...

Comment: @Topdown What's your use case? Isn't [`Table`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) enough?

Comment: Two other notes: First, `Multimap<K1, Multimap<K2, V>>` is probably more than you need. How about `Map<K1, Multimap<K2, V>>`? (Possibly even better would be `Table<K1, K2, List<V>>`.) Second, note that `ArrayListMultimap` does not guarantee the order of its elements. So "normal order" and "reverse order" are no particular order, and they may even change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Slurp all of your values into a `List` and reverse that `List`, then iterate over it:

```
final List<Multimap<String, String>> allValues 
    = Lists.newArrayList(stockMatrix.values());

Collections.reverse(allValues);

// iterate over allValues
```

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks to all that tried to help. I realise my questions are pretty basic but I am just starting into this. My requirement is to have all keys and all values able to hold duplicates, this is why I was trying to use Multimap at both levels. Cheers.

Comment: Well, a table can do that for you; the difference is that your keys would become rows, your values'keys columns and your values' values lists or something

Comment: Note that if you just want to iterate over a `List` in reverse order, `Lists.reverse(List)` is probably a better choice than `Collections.reverse`. It creates a view of the list rather than having to actually move the elements around.